# Angular 8 universal, runtime compiler not loaded error while loading lazy loaded modules on server side

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to load different modules based on my device type via lazy loading. that is, if the user is on mobile, i need to load the mobile module and desktop module for desktop users. this works fine in browser. however when i enable angular universal, loading the lazyloaded module routes giving me error 'runtime compiler not loaded' in the server side part.

I created a small app to show this issue, please check if possible, all my configurations (package.json, tsconfig, etc) are accessible in this repo.  https://github.com/devbenzy/angularserverside

Please check and advise what i am doing wrong here.